Print function using Spreadsheetgear
I have created the program to print the workbookview using spreadsheetgear in which if the cancel button clicked in the print dialogue then the message box should show "print operation cancelled by user", in the below code, it always shows print completed. (msgbox)
Public Sub PrintWorksheet(workbookView As SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView, username As String, drawingNo As String, systemName As String, version As String)
    Dim desiredPrinter As String = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    Dim printerAvailable As Boolean = False

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

    For Each printer As String In PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
        If printer = desiredPrinter Then
            printerAvailable = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not printerAvailable Then
        MessageBox.Show("Microsoft Print to PDF is not installed or not available. Please install it or set it as your default printer.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return
    End If

    Dim activeWorksheet As IWorksheet = workbookView.ActiveWorksheet
    If activeWorksheet IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim workbookSet As IWorkbookSet = activeWorksheet.Workbook.WorkbookSet
        workbookSet.GetLock()

        Try
            Dim printDocument As New WorkbookPrintDocument(activeWorksheet, PrintWhat.Sheet)
            If printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF" Then
                activeWorksheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = $"&B&U&11&""Arial""Prepared By : {username}"
                activeWorksheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = $"{systemName} - {DateTime.Now:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - V - {version}"

                Try
                    printDocument.Print()
                    MessageBox.Show("Print Completed", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    LogToDatabase(username, version, "Static Beam calculation Printed", drawingNo, CommonDataManager.IterationNumber, systemName)
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
                    'Catch ex As Exception When TypeOf ex Is InvalidPrinterException OrElse ex.HResult = &H80004005
                    'MessageBox.Show("Print cancelled by user.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

                Catch ex As Exception When TypeOf ex Is InvalidPrinterException OrElse ex.HResult = &H80004005
                    MessageBox.Show("Printing was cancelled by the user.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)


                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show($"Printing failed: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Printer not found or not valid.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        Finally
            workbookSet.ReleaseLock()
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No active worksheet to print.")
    End If

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
End Sub

End Module
